# Haman going to the second feast dirty

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, haman

In all story tapes/videos I've seen it always portrays that Haman was taken to Esther's second feast dirty while in the Megillah all it says is just that they took him while "he was still talking" "עודם מדבּרים עמּוֹ"  which could be understood as whether he was ready or not but it doesn't say anything about if he got cleaned up or not. Does anybody know of any source that says he was taken before he got a chance to clean up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Talmud ([*Megillah* 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.16a.16?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)) states:

> וסריסי המלך הגיעו ויבהילו מלמד שהביאוהו בבהלה.‏
>
> "The king’s chamberlains came, and they hastened" - This teaches that they brought him in disarray.

On which Rashi (ibid.) comments:

> מלמד שהביאוהו בבהלה - ולא רחץ יפה מטינופו
>
> This teaches that they brought him in disarray - And he did not wash properly from his filth.